# How to implement a whatsapp mobile scroll effect in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface

I am trying to implement the scrolling effect on the home screen on whatsap on iphone, where the search bar disappears first while scrolling the the rest of the scrolling takes place. Any idea on how to implement it ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the [SliverAppBar](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SliverAppBar-class.html) with a [CustomScrollView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CustomScrollView-class.html).

```
return Scaffold(
  //1
  body: CustomScrollView(
    slivers: <Widget>[
      //2
      SliverAppBar(
        expandedHeight: 250.0,
        flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
          title: Text('Goa', textScaleFactor: 1),
          background: Image.asset(
            'assets/images/beach.png',
            fit: BoxFit.fill,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      //3
      SliverList(
        delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
          (_, int index) {
            return ListTile(
              leading: Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                  width: 100,
                  child: Placeholder()),
              title: Text('Place ${index + 1}', textScaleFactor: 2),
            );
          },
          childCount: 20,
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```